# What is the maximum number of Firebase shards we can have?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As the title say: What is the maximum number of Firebase shards we can have?

I just realized that one Firebase database is not going to cut it for my project, because the real-time DB price scales very harshly. I could avoid the issue by having one main DB where I go on Blaze and a very large amount of small DB instances on spark. Alternatively, I could use storage (which scales much better), but I'd have to do some significant change in how my program works.

Comment: " because the storage price scales very harshly" do you mean Realtime Database here?

Comment: yes, real-time database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an undocumented limit to the number of projects you can have on the free/Spark plan. The number depends on the reputation of your account on the Google Cloud Platform. Since Firebase projects are also GCP projects, the limit covers both your Firebase and (plain) GCP projects.

There is no known limit to the number of projects you can have on a paid plan.